# Как сделать из float число int python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, float, int

Проблема такая. Есть, например, две переменные, одна из них float, а другая - int или тоже float. И может получиться такое, что при вычислении одного числа из другого получается целое число, например: 2.62 - 1.62 = 1.0
Как убрать этот ноль и точку в конце числа?

Comment: Вообще это больше вопрос представления. В чём собственно ваша проблема - непонятно. Вы просите решения, не обозначив реальную проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для начала надо разобраться для чего удалять `0`

превратить число с плавающей запятой в целое можно функцией `int`

```
a = 3.14
b = 2.78

c = int(a - b)
```

если же выводить на экран без дробной части, то можно использовать функцию `format` и вообще представление числа с плавающей запятой как `.0f`

если же хочется превращать число с плавающей запятой в целое, только когда оно целое, то можно сделать так:

```
c = int(c) if c == float(int(c)) else c
```

Comment: float в последней строчке можно убрать, на результат не повлияет.

Answer (score 0):

еще можно воспользоваться встроенной функции round

Comment: нельзя, результат может неприятно удивить

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]